# Preserving environment variables in CMake

Tags: environment-variables, cmake

I am working on something that requires some header files from a different source tree. For various reasons, I would like to keep these headers outside of my project and reference them during the make process.

I have a CMake build script that generates my makefiles, but I would like to be able to generate makefiles with references to environment variables in them, such that the generated makefile can be run like so:

```
HEADERS=/somewhere/on/the/filesystem make
```

Is this possible using CMake? Failing that, is there a way to get what I'm after using CMake only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_PORT "$(TARGET_SERIAL_PORT)")
```

It's a real-world example but I hope it gives you an idea. You can assign a string to a variable which will be copied verbatim to the Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) using the TARGET and PRE_LINK options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ENV{VARIABLE}` to get the value of an environment variable, but it will only be evaluated during the cmake run and not during the make.

Answer (score 0):

For passing environment variable to make, you can:

```
CMAKE_POLICY(PUSH)
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0005 NEW)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHEADER=$ENV{HEADER})
CMAKE_POLICY(POP)
```

Replace `HEADER` to whatever your variable name.

Setting cmake policy `CMP0005` is for cmake to generate correct escape for you.